# C# Windows Forms user control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I create a custom grid control by extending the DataGridView in windows forms application. I use some custom functions for setting column readonly and some other functionalities. My current problem is when I use multiple controls in same form, it only reflects function execution output for the last control only. How make each control a separate instance of the user control?

```
    public partial class dGridView : DataGridView
{
    #region Member variables
    DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell chkHeader;
    bool NeedToPopulateColumns = true;

    public event DatagridViewCellButtonClickedHandler CellButtonClicked;

    private int currentComboSelIndex;
    #endregion

    public dGridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            this.CellButtonClicked += new DatagridViewCellButtonClickedHandler(dGridView_CellButtonClicked);
        }
    }

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the datasource used to define columns.
    /// </summary>
    public object DesignDataSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public bool ExtendLastColumn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<string> AutoFilterColumnNames
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<string> HiddenColumnsList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<string> ReadOnlyColumnsList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<string> ButtonColumnsList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<DGVSupportClass.ComboBoxColumns> ComboBoxColumnsList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<CustomCaptions> customCaptionList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    #region Public Methods
    public void AddFilterToColumns(List<string> columnNames)
    {
        if (columnNames.Count > 0)
        {
            this.AutoFilterColumnNames = columnNames;
        }
    }

    public void HiddenColumns(List<string> columnNames)
    {
        if (columnNames.Count > 0)
        {
            this.HiddenColumnsList = columnNames;

            HideColumnsInList(this.HiddenColumnsList);
        }
    }

    public void ReadOnlyColumns(List<string> columnNames)
    {
        if (columnNames.Count > 0)
        {
            this.ReadOnlyColumnsList = columnNames;

            ReadOnlyColumnsInList(this.ReadOnlyColumnsList);
        }
    }

    public void ReadOnlyRow(int rowIndex)
    {
        if (this.DataSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.Rows[rowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
    }

    public void AddButtonToCells(List<string> columnNames)
    {
        this.ButtonColumnsList = columnNames;

        NeedToPopulateColumns = true;
        FindBindingDataObjectType();
    }

    public void AddComboBoxColumn(List<DGVSupportClass.ComboBoxColumns> comboBoxColumns)
    {
        this.ComboBoxColumnsList = comboBoxColumns;

        NeedToPopulateColumns = true;

        FindBindingDataObjectType();
    }

    public void SetCustomDataSourceToComboBoxCell(int colIndex, int rowIndex, object cboxDataSource, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        if (this.Columns[colIndex].GetType() != typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn))
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Column [{0}] is not a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn", colIndex));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayMember) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueMember))
        {
            throw new Exception("Display and Value Member must be passed");
        }

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo = this[colIndex, rowIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

        combo.DataSource = cboxDataSource;
        combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        combo.ValueMember = valueMember;
    }

    public void SetCustomDataSourceToComboBoxCell(int colIndex, int rowIndex, string[] cboxDataSource)
    {
        if (this.Columns[colIndex].GetType() != typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn))
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Column [{0}] is not a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn", colIndex));
        }

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo = this[colIndex, rowIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

        combo.DataSource = cboxDataSource;
    }

    public void CustomColumnCaptions(List<CustomCaptions> newColumnCaptions)
    {
        if (newColumnCaptions == null || newColumnCaptions.GetType() == typeof(System.DBNull))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.customCaptionList != newColumnCaptions)
            this.customCaptionList = newColumnCaptions;

        foreach (CustomCaptions col in newColumnCaptions)
        {
            if (this.Columns[col.ColumnName] != null)
                this.Columns[col.ColumnName].HeaderCell.Value = col.ColumnCaption;
        }
    }

    public void SetCustomColumnCaption(string columnName, string newCaption)
    {
        if (this.Columns.Contains(columnName))
        {
            if (this.Columns[columnName] != null)
                this.Columns[columnName].HeaderCell.Value = newCaption;
        }

        CustomCaptions cap = new CustomCaptions(columnName, newCaption);

        if (!customCaptionList.Contains(cap))
        {
            customCaptionList.Add(cap);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private void AddFilterToColumnsInList(List<string> columnNames)
    {
        if (this.DataSource == null || columnNames == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in this.Columns)
        {
            if (col.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) && columnNames.Contains(col.Name))
                col.HeaderCell = new
                    DataGridViewAutoFilter.DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(col.HeaderCell);
        }

    }

    private void HideColumnsInList(List<string> columnNames)
    {
        if (this.DataSource == null || columnNames == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in this.Columns)
        {
            if (this.HiddenColumnsList.Contains(col.Name))
            {
                col.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the type of the binding data object.
    /// </summary>
    private void FindBindingDataObjectType()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
        if (NeedToPopulateColumns)
        {
            if (this.DataSource is System.Collections.IList && this.DataSource.GetType().IsGenericType)
            {
                PopulateDataGridColumnsFromICartItem();
            }

            else
            {
                PopulateDataGridColumnsFromDataView();
            }

            NeedToPopulateColumns = false;

            if (this.customCaptionList != null && this.customCaptionList.GetType() != typeof(System.DBNull))
            {
                CustomColumnCaptions(this.customCaptionList);
            }
        }
        this.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the DataGridView columns with controls according to the
    /// DataType of each columns which it represents. e.g. when a boolean 
    /// value found, then a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn will be added and 
    /// for datetime it will be ESCalendarColumn (a custom control).
    /// </summary>
    private void PopulateDataGridColumnsFromDataView()
    {
        bool isComboAdded = false;
        DataTable dt = null;

        if (null == this.DataSource)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (this.DataSource.GetType().ToString())
            {
                case "System.Data.DataTable":
                    dt = (DataTable)this.DataSource;
                    break;
                case "System.Data.DataView":
                    dt = ((DataView)this.DataSource).Table;
                    break;
                case "System.Data.DataSet":
                    dt = ((DataSet)this.DataSource).Tables[0];
                    break;
                case "System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource":
                    if (((BindingSource)this.DataSource).DataSource.GetType() == typeof(DataTable))
                    {
                        dt = (DataTable)((BindingSource)this.DataSource).DataSource;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
        }

        this.Columns.Clear();

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (ButtonColumnsList != null && ButtonColumnsList.Contains(dc.ColumnName))
            {
                DataGridViewButtonColumn dvButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                dvButton.Name = dc.ColumnName;
                dvButton.HeaderText = dc.ColumnName;

                this.Columns.Add(dvButton);
                this.Columns[dvButton.Name].DataPropertyName = dvButton.Name;

                continue;
            }

            if (ComboBoxColumnsList != null && ComboBoxColumnsList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DGVSupportClass.ComboBoxColumns tmpData in ComboBoxColumnsList)
                {
                    if (tmpData.ColumnName == dc.ColumnName)
                    {
                        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                        comboCol.DataPropertyName = dc.ColumnName;
                        comboCol.Name = dc.ColumnName;
                        comboCol.HeaderText = dc.ColumnName;
                        comboCol.DataSource = tmpData.DataSource;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpData.Display))
                        {
                            comboCol.DisplayMember = tmpData.Display;
                            comboCol.ValueMember = tmpData.Value;
                        }
                        comboCol.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
                        comboCol.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;

                        this.Columns.Add(comboCol);
                        isComboAdded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isComboAdded)
            {
                isComboAdded = false;
                continue;
            }

            switch (((DataColumn)dc).DataType.ToString())
            {
                case "System.String":
                case "System.Int32":
                case "System.Int64":
                case "System.Decimal":
                case "System.Guid":
                    this.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.Caption);
                    this.Columns[dc.ColumnName].DataPropertyName = dc.ColumnName;
                    this.Columns[dc.ColumnName].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
                    break;
                case "System.Boolean":
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkbox = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                    chkHeader = new DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell();

                    chkbox.HeaderCell = chkHeader;
                    chkbox.Name = "chkBox" + dc.ColumnName;
                    chkbox.HeaderText = dc.ColumnName;
                    chkHeader.OnCheckBoxClicked += new CheckBoxClickedHandler(chkHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked);

                    this.Columns.Add(chkbox);
                    this.Columns[chkbox.Name].DataPropertyName = dc.ColumnName;
                    this.Columns[chkbox.Name].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    this.Columns[chkbox.Name].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
                    break;
                case "System.DateTime":
                    ESCalendarColumn calendarCol = new ESCalendarColumn();
                    calendarCol.Name = ((DataColumn)dc).ColumnName;
                    calendarCol.HeaderText = ((DataColumn)dc).Caption;

                    this.Columns.Add(calendarCol);
                    this.Columns[calendarCol.Name].DataPropertyName = calendarCol.Name;
                    this.Columns[calendarCol.Name].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (((DataColumn)dc).DataType.IsEnum)
                    {
                        List<DGVSupportClass.EnumToComboClass> lstCbo = new List<DGVSupportClass.EnumToComboClass>();
                        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                        comboCol.DataPropertyName = ((DataColumn)dc).ColumnName;
                        comboCol.Name = ((DataColumn)dc).ColumnName;
                        comboCol.HeaderText = ((DataColumn)dc).Caption;
                        comboCol.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(dc.DataType);
                        comboCol.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
                        if (((DataColumn)dc).ReadOnly) comboCol.ReadOnly = true;
                        this.Columns.Add(comboCol);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.Caption);
                        this.Columns[dc.ColumnName].DataPropertyName = dc.ColumnName;
                        this.Columns[dc.ColumnName].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        NeedToPopulateColumns = false;

        AddFilterToColumnsInList(this.AutoFilterColumnNames);
        HideColumnsInList(this.HiddenColumnsList);

        // Extend the last column
        if (this.ExtendLastColumn)
        {
            this.Columns[this.Columns.Count - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the DataGridView columns with controls according to the
    /// DataType of each columns which it represents. e.g. when a boolean
    /// value found, then a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn will be added and
    /// for datetime it will be ESCalendarColumn (a custom control).
    /// </summary>
    private void PopulateDataGridColumnsFromICartItem()
    {
        this.Columns.Clear();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = null;
        bool isComboAdded = false;

        if (this.DesignDataSource != null)
        {
            if (this.DesignDataSource != null && this.DesignDataSource is System.Collections.IList && this.DesignDataSource.GetType().IsGenericType)
            {
                if (((System.Collections.IList)this.DesignDataSource).Count > 0 && (((System.Collections.IList)this.DesignDataSource)[0]) != null)
                {
                    propertyInfos = (((System.Collections.IList)this.DesignDataSource)[0]).GetType().GetProperties();
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyInfos = this.DesignDataSource.GetType().GetProperties();
                    propertyInfos = propertyInfos[propertyInfos.Length - 1].PropertyType.GetProperties();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.DataSource != null && this.DataSource is System.Collections.IList && this.DataSource.GetType().IsGenericType)
            {
                if (((System.Collections.IList)this.DataSource).Count > 0)
                {
                    propertyInfos = (((System.Collections.IList)this.DataSource)[0]).GetType().GetProperties();
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyInfos = this.DataSource.GetType().GetProperties();
                    propertyInfos = propertyInfos[propertyInfos.Length - 1].PropertyType.GetProperties();
                }
            }
        }

        if (propertyInfos != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in propertyInfos)
            {
                if (ComboBoxColumnsList != null && ComboBoxColumnsList.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DGVSupportClass.ComboBoxColumns tmpData in ComboBoxColumnsList)
                    {
                        if (tmpData.ColumnName == item.Name)
                        {
                            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                            comboCol.DataPropertyName = item.Name;
                            comboCol.Name = item.Name;
                            comboCol.HeaderText = item.Name;
                            comboCol.DataSource = tmpData.DataSource;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpData.Display))
                            {
                                comboCol.DisplayMember = tmpData.Display;
                                comboCol.ValueMember = tmpData.Value;
                            }
                            comboCol.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
                            comboCol.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;

                            this.Columns.Add(comboCol);
                            isComboAdded = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isComboAdded)
                {
                    isComboAdded = false;
                    continue;
                }

                if (ButtonColumnsList != null && ButtonColumnsList.Contains(item.Name))
                {
                    DataGridViewButtonColumn dvButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                    dvButton.Name = item.Name;
                    dvButton.HeaderText = item.Name;

                    this.Columns.Add(dvButton);
                    this.Columns[dvButton.Name].DataPropertyName = dvButton.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (item.PropertyType.ToString())
                    {
                        case "System.String":
                        case "System.Int32":
                        case "System.Int64":
                        case "System.Decimal":
                        case "System.Guid":
                            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtBox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                            txtBox.Name = item.Name;

                            this.Columns.Add(txtBox);
                            this.Columns[item.Name].DataPropertyName = item.Name;

                            break;
                        case "System.Boolean":
                            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkbox = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                            chkHeader = new DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell();

                            chkbox.HeaderCell = chkHeader;
                            chkbox.Name = "chkBox" + item.Name;
                            chkbox.HeaderText = item.Name;
                            chkHeader.OnCheckBoxClicked += new CheckBoxClickedHandler(chkHeader_OnCheckBoxClicked);

                            this.Columns.Add(chkbox);
                            this.Columns[chkbox.Name].DataPropertyName = item.Name;
                            this.Columns[chkbox.Name].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                            this.Columns[chkbox.Name].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
                            break;
                        case "System.DateTime":
                            ESCalendarColumn calendarCol = new ESCalendarColumn();
                            calendarCol.Name = item.Name;
                            calendarCol.HeaderText = item.Name;

                            this.Columns.Add(calendarCol);
                            this.Columns[calendarCol.Name].DataPropertyName = calendarCol.Name;

                            break;

                        default:
                            if (item.PropertyType.IsEnum && item.PropertyType.IsPublic)
                            {
                                List<DGVSupportClass.EnumToComboClass> lstCbo = new List<DGVSupportClass.EnumToComboClass>();

                                foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fInfo in item.PropertyType.GetFields(
                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static))
                                {
                                    lstCbo.Add(new DGVSupportClass.EnumToComboClass(fInfo.Name, fInfo.GetRawConstantValue().ToString()));
                                }

                                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                                comboCol.DataPropertyName = item.Name;
                                comboCol.Name = item.Name;
                                comboCol.HeaderText = item.Name;
                                comboCol.DataSource = lstCbo;
                                comboCol.DisplayMember = "Display";
                                comboCol.ValueMember = "Value";
                                comboCol.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;

                                this.Columns.Add(comboCol);
                            }
                            else if (!item.PropertyType.IsAbstract)
                            {
                                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtBoxDefault = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                                txtBoxDefault.Name = item.Name;
                                txtBoxDefault.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;

                                this.Columns.Add(txtBoxDefault);
                                this.Columns[item.Name].DataPropertyName = item.Name;
                            }
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (this.ExtendLastColumn)
        {
            this.Columns[this.Columns.Count - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        }

        AddFilterToColumnsInList(this.AutoFilterColumnNames);
        HideColumnsInList(this.HiddenColumnsList);
    }

    #endregion
    #endregion

    #region Events
    protected override void OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DesignDataSource == null)
        {
            this.DesignDataSource = this.DataSource;
            NeedToPopulateColumns = true;
        }

        FindBindingDataObjectType();

        base.OnDataSourceChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnCellContentClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonColumn))
        {
            DatagridViewCellButtonClickEventArgs dc = new DatagridViewCellButtonClickEventArgs(this.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(),
                this.CurrentCell.Tag, this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, this.CurrentCell.RowIndex, this.CurrentCell.Value);

            if (CellButtonClicked != null) { CellButtonClicked(this, dc); }
        }
        else if (this.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn))
        {
            this.CurrentCell = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            this.BeginEdit(false);
            ComboBox comboBox = this.EditingControl as ComboBox;
            if (comboBox != null)
            {
                comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
            }
        }

        base.OnCellContentClick(e);
    }

    protected override void OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn))
        {
            this.CurrentCell = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            this.BeginEdit(false);
            ComboBox comboBox = this.EditingControl as ComboBox;
            if (comboBox != null)
            {
                comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
            }
        }
        base.OnCellClick(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDataBindingComplete(DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDataBindingComplete(e);
    }

    protected override void OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            List<ColumnSettingsClass> LCss = new List<ColumnSettingsClass>();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in this.Columns)
            {
                if (!HiddenColumnsList.Contains(col.Name))
                {
                    LCss.Add(new ColumnSettingsClass(col.Name, col.HeaderText, col.Width, col.Index, col.Visible));
                }
            }
            ColumnSettings frmCs = new ColumnSettings(ref LCss);
            frmCs.ShowDialog(this);

            foreach (ColumnSettingsClass item in LCss)
            {
                if (this.Columns.Contains(item.ColumnName))
                {
                    this.Columns[item.ColumnName].DisplayIndex = item.ColumnOrdinal;
                    this.Columns[item.ColumnName].Width = item.ColumnWidth;
                    this.Columns[item.ColumnName].Visible = item.Visibility;
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(e);
    }

    protected override void OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(e);
        this.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

    protected override void OnEditingControlShowing(DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(LastColumnComboSelectionChanged);
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(LastColumnComboSelectionChanged);

            if (comboBox != null)
                comboBox.DropDown += delegate(object s, EventArgs se) { ((ComboBox)s).BackColor = this.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor; };
        }

        base.OnEditingControlShowing(e);
    }

    private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentcell = this.CurrentCellAddress;
        var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;

        if (sendingCB.EditingControlValueChanged)
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)this.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[0];
            cel.Value = sendingCB.EditingControlFormattedValue.ToString();
        }
        sendingCB.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(LastColumnComboSelectionChanged);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code????

Comment: Please add code of your control and how you call / adding control to form.

Comment: That headline should be updated to actually describe the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different instances of the UserControl, I usually do so. 
MyUserControl myUc MyUserControl = new ();

> ```
>     public MyUserControl CALLED= null;
>     private void FrmXXXXX_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         MyUserControl  uc = new MyUserControl ();
>         uc.VALUE = this.VALUE;
>         uc.CALLER = this;
>         uc.Parent = pnlMain;
>         uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
>     }
> ```

This way you can create many different UserControl equal but different instances in memory and behavior

Comment: I added the usercontrol at design time and the .Designer code is well created each user control as separate instance, but at runtime it behaves abnormally.

Comment: UsercControl you must create them at runtime do this test .

Comment: Is there any other option to manage the instance in user control code itself?

Comment: The test Mr.deniele3004 suggested is not rectified my problem. Is there any other option to manage the instance in user control itself?